# $belongsTo relationship not working cakephp 2.7.5

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to link two models to work in my cakephp 2.7.5 app.

The trouble is when I try to add a new 'User' the form does not show the "select" with options of 'Departamentos' that I have created.

Code is:

*app\Model\User.php*

```
<?php

class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = "User";
    public $belongsTo = array('Departamento' => array('className' => 'Departamento', 'foreignKey' => 'departamento_id'));
...
```

*app\Model\Departamento.php*

```
<?php

class Departamento extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'nombre';
    public $name = "Departamento";
    public $hasMany = array('User' => array('className' => 'User', 'foreignKey' => 'departamento_id'));

}
```

This is the MySQL Script:

```
create table users(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    nombre varchar(200),
    username varchar(20) not null,
    password varchar(100) not null,
    rol varchar(50) not null,
    departamento_id int
);

create table departamentos(
     id int primary key auto_increment,
    nombre varchar(200) not null
);
```

My *app\View\Users\add.ctp* code:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('nombre', array('label' => 'Nombre Completo:'));
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Nombre de usuario:'));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password', 'label' => 'Contraseña:'));
echo $this->Form->input('rol', array('label' => 'Rol del usuario:', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => array('ADMINISTRADOR' => 'Administrador', 'USUARIO' => 'Usuario')));
echo $this->Form->input('departamento_id', array('label' => 'Departamento:'));
echo $this->Form->end('Guardar');
```

I have added the inflection rules to my spanish named tables:

```
Inflector::rules('plural', array('irregular' => array('departamento' => 'departamentos')));
```

This is a screenshot of my 'add user' form, The field "Departamento" appears empty, but there is data in my "Departamentos" table:

[Add Form with empty field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNVgQ.png)

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your add action from `UsersController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following:

```
$this->set('departamentos',$this->User->Departamento->find('list',array('order'=>'nombre')));
```

in your `UsersController::add()` function. CakePHP should automatically create the SELECT options from the $departamentos variable in the view.